# Change value in nested document in MongoDB-array

Tags: mongodb

I have document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5152ba0708c164359d5ca616"),
        "info": "Some interesting information.",
    "elements" : [
        {
            "status" : "accepted",
            "id" : "10"
        },
                {
            "status" : "waiting",
            "id" : "20"
        },
                {
            "status" : "accepted",
            "id" : "30"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I modify "status" to "accepted" where "status" is "waiting" and "id" is 20?

Comment: You do not want to check status and id at the same time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use positional ("$") operator.

```
// single
db.collection.update({ _id: ..., "elements.id": "20" }, { $set: { "elements.$.status": "status" } })

// all
db.collection.update({ "elements.id": "20" }, { $set: { "elements.$.status": "status" } }, { multi: true  })
```

Comment: Where are you checking for the "waiting" status ? If you only check for 20 you may get those elements also where the status is already "accepted"

Comment: db.collection.update({ "_id": ..., "elements.id": "20" }, { "$set": { "elements.$.status": "status" } })

Answer (score 1):

You have to use elemMatch (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) . To match both the items of the array like status and id 20 , then you can use the $set command. The reason behind using elemMatch is that it will make sure that both the criteria is matched on the same subdocument before returning the result

```
db.CollectionName.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5152ba0708c164359d5ca616") , "elements" : { "$elemMatch : {"status" : "waiting" , "Id" : "20"}}},{ $set : {"elements.$.status" : "accepted"}});
```